# swiftydropbox and server side use of access token

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swiftydropbox

I am starting to use SwiftyDropbox on my iOS client, and my plan is to get the access token after successful sign-in by the user, and then send that access token to my server-- so it can make use of the users Dropbox. (This makes sense in the context of my app).

Is this the right flow? Will the access token be usable on my server?

Before I started putting SwiftyDropbox into my client app, I was reading https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide and that seemed to indicate I should send the authorization code to my server, and have it get the access token using the authorization code. Some other OAuth2 systems (e.g., Google) require this kind of flow (e.g., with Google you send an authorization code to the server, which it redeems for a refresh token, from which you get access tokens).

Answer (score 0):

This does work on the server, so I assume it is the right flow. No authorization code is required on the server, just the same access token that works on the client.